# check checkboxes by variable in array

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Code:

```
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' lid='1'><label>checkbox1</label>
    <input type='checkbox' lid='2'><label>checkbox1</label>
    <input type='checkbox' lid='3'><label>checkbox1</label>
    <input type='checkbox' lid='4'><label>checkbox1</label>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var arr = new Array("1", "2");
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
        $.inArray($(this).attr('lid'), arr){
            $(this).attr('checked','checked')
        }
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to check all the checkboxes that have the same 'lid' as an item in an array.
Right now, my function, checks all the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't using an `if` statement:

```
$.inArray($(this).attr('lid'), arr){
    $(this).attr('checked','checked')
}
```

should be

```
if (-1 !== $.inArray($(this).attr('lid'), arr)){
    $(this).attr('checked','checked')
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferable to use `.prop` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

[$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) passes back a number where -1 is it's not found so you should do it like this

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
        var found = $.inArray($(this).attr('lid'), arr) > -1;
        if(found){
           $(this).attr('checked','checked')
        }
 });
```

If using jQuery 1.6+ you should be using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of .attr to set the checked property of the element

```
$(this).prop('checked',true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to check the checkboxes!

And [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns the position, so make it > -1

```
 var arr = ['1','2'];

 $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
     var cb = $(this);

     if ($.inArray(cb.attr('lid'), arr) > -1) {
         cb.prop('checked', true);
     }
 });
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/4kehu/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple for loop

```
var arr = new Array("1", "2");

for(var i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var lid = arr[i];
    $('input[type="checkbox"][lid="'+ lid +'"]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqTHA/)**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `data-lid` instead of `lid`, i.e.

```
<input type='checkbox' data-lid='1'><label>checkbox1</label>
```

and use to check those checkboxes

```
var arr = ["1", "2"];
var myCBoxes=$('input[type=checkbox]').get().filter(function(el){
    return $.inArray($(el).attr('data-lid'), arr)!=-1;
});
$(myCBoxes).prop('checked','checked');
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsbin.com/odoquj/3/edit).